# Is it possible to use Apache NiFi as dataflow engine for MS SQL Server in-database computations?

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi, dataflow

Is it possible to use Apache NiFi as dataflow engine for MS SQL Server in-database computations?

In other words, I would like to use Apache NiFi as if I used Alteryx.

For example, can I execute two or more MS SQL procedures sequentially from within Apache NiFi?

Can you suggest alternative tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pricipal you could use NiFi for this but not ideal.

Apache NiFi supports **DBCPConnectionPool** and you can connect to preatty much all DBs that have a JDBC connector and yes you will be able to run MS SQL proc sequentially.

**DBCPConnectionPool** setup requires you have the jdbc jar on your NiFi server and in the parameter setup you can use this settings

- **Connect URL** :jdbc:sqlserver://ip:port
- **Driver Class** : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
- **Driver Location** : /opt/nifi/external_libs/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar

  If you have ETL type workload then where you will pump large amounts of data from one point to another having the NiFi server doing alot of I/O on large files i would not recommend NiFI.